# How to define hidden column in Xrm grid

Tags: dynamics-crm, xrm

Is there a way how to include hidden column in xrm grid/view ?

Say I have saved query definition like:

```
<savedquery>
  <savedqueryid>{...}</savedqueryid>
  <layoutxml>
    <grid name="resultset" jump="name" select="1" icon="1" preview="1">
      <row name="result" id="entityid">
        <cell name="name" width="200" />
        <cell name="statuscode" width="100" />   
      </row>
    </grid>
  </layoutxml>
  <querytype>0</querytype>
  <fetchxml>
    <fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical">
      <entity name="entity">
        <attribute name="name" />
        <attribute name="statuscode" />
      </entity>
    </fetch>
  </fetchxml>
</savedquery>
```

What I'm after is having the column in grid accessible via client api - as it drives the ribbon logic

```
var allSelectedRows = gridContext.getGrid().getSelectedRows().forEach((row) => {
  // this doesn't work if grid doesn't contain statuscode column
  let status = row.data.entity.attributes.get("statuscode");

});
```

Without actually showing the column in UI.

Answer (score 0):

Technically not possible, unfortunately. As there is no property to set hidden columns, also not advisable to do/read unsupported DOM elements access.

You can use `SelectedControlSelectedItemIds` to pass as a parameter to custom JavaScript and then you can pull the needed column like `statuscode` from server to do validation.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/customize-dev/pass-dynamics-365-data-page-parameter-ribbon-actions#grid-values

Comment: This of course works, but it is problematic (kind of) since ribbon is a synchronous-only so only way is to show something by default, request fetch, and then force refresh-ribbon - not exactly elegant.

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar probably you can submit this idea to MS.. like giving option to add hidden columns in gridview